# How to distinguish between what action was implemented on Listbox menu?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void contextMenuStripListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    listBoxFiles.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex);
}
```

i have Listbox with right click menu, each option planned to do different action (delete, show statistics...)
after right click on item in my list box and choose option from the menu how can i distinguish what action was implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

You should attach click hanlders to each menu item, not the menu itself.

Comment: on each option from the menu ?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, in that click handler you showed, you can cast the sender to `MenuItem` and perform action based on it's name or other property.